# App get crashed on method call of button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

My app get crashed when i clicked on button here is my code

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
-(void)btnClicked
{
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code and try this

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thanks it works. you give the first reply so i am going to accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Your selector ends with a colon (:). It means the method has a parameter. Either remove the colon:

```
@selector(btnClicked)
```

Or add a parameter to the method declaration:

```
- (void)btnClicked:(id)sender {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have a mistake in your code:

If you do this:

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then your method should be like this:

```
-(void)buttonCliked:(id)sender{}
```

If you do this:

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then your method should be like this:

```
-(void)buttonCliked{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon.

It should be like this:

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Since you are using btnClicked, you need to use

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Change the method to this

```
- (void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
}
```